# How to fix maven file encoding issues?

Tags: java, maven, utf-8, maven-compiler-plugin

My project,which is in Java, is completely in UTF-8, but when I try to compile it with maven to UTF-8, it has tons of errors, on mostly lines, that don't exist.

When I cut the file contents, of the affected file, run maven, paste it and run it again, it removes the issue. However I don't want to do it for 20+ files.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project piinfo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,4] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,9] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,10] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,13] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,14] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,16] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,20] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,23] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,28] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,29] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,30] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,34] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,36] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,39] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,42] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,46] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,47] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,49] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,51] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,53] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,54] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,56] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,57] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,58] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,60] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,61] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,64] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,65] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,70] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,73] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,75] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,79] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,81] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,86] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,89] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,90] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,92] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,95] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,96] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,97] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,103] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,107] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,109] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,111] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,112] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,114] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,119] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,120] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,122] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,126] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,127] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,133] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,135] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,137] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,142] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,143] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,145] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,149] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,151] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,159] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,160] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,164] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,166] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,169] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,171] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,174] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,176] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,1] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,7] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,12] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,20] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,25] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,28] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,33] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,35] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,37] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,38] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,42] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,43] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,46] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,47] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,49] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,51] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,52] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,54] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,55] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,56] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,60] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,61] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,63] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,65] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,70] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,71] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,72] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,74] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,82] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,86] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,89] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,91] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,2] illegal character: '\'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,3] illegal character: '\u0003'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,4] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,9] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,10] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,11] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,13] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,14] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,15] illegal character: '\u0019'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,16] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,70] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,73] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,75] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,76] illegal character: '\u007f'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,77] illegal character: '\u0006'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,79] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,81] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,85] illegal character: '\u001f'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,86] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,88] illegal character: '\'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,89] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,90] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,92] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,94] illegal character: '\u00b9'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,95] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,96] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,97] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,98] illegal character: '\'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,103] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,107] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,109] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,111] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,112] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,113] illegal character: '\u000b'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,114] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,115] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,118] illegal character: '\u001e'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,119] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,120] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,122] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,126] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,127] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,133] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,135] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,137] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,142] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,143] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,144] illegal character: '\u0000'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,145] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,148] illegal character: '\u000b'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,149] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,150] illegal character: '\u0003'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,151] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,152] illegal character: '\u0014'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,158] illegal character: '\u001b'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,159] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,160] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,161] illegal character: '\u0012'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,164] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,166] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,167] illegal character: '\u000e'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,169] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,171] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,174] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[1,176] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,1] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,7] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,10] unclosed character literal
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,12] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,20] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,22] illegal character: '\'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,25] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,28] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,33] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,35] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,36] illegal character: '`'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,37] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,38] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,39] illegal character: '\u007f'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,40] illegal character: '\u0004'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,42] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,43] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,46] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,47] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,48] illegal character: '\u06e9'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,49] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,50] illegal character: '`'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,51] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,52] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,54] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,55] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,56] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,60] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,61] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,63] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,65] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,70] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,71] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,72] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java:[2,74] illegal character: '\ufffd'
```

first two lines of /Volumes/NO NAME/Springboot/src/main/java/com/piinfo/config/WebSecuretyController.java

```
package com.piinfo.config;
```

If I'm compiling from UTF-8 to UTF-8, it should have no issues, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happened is, that my files ended up corrupted (not ejecting my usb one time) and it wasn't yet showing in the editor.

After coming back and plugging my usb back in, the files were obviously corrupted so much, that I had to revert them to my latest commit.